# PBJVision CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.094 seconds, timescale 24)

Tags: ios, video-capture, pbjvision

I am using PBJVision in a swift project I am having the following issue on ending the capture session.

CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.094 seconds, timescale 24): warning: error of -0.011 introduced due to very low timescale

This doesn't allow me to save videos to photos and giving me the following error on saving:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"

I have searched for it a lot but not found a solution.

here is my code

```
vision.cameraMode = PBJCameraMode.Video
vision.audioBitRate = 44
vision.cameraOrientation = PBJCameraOrientation.Portrait
vision.focusMode = PBJFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus
vision.outputFormat = PBJOutputFormat.Standard
vision.videoRenderingEnabled = true
vision.additionalCompressionProperties = [AVVideoProfileLevelKey : AVVideoProfileLevelH264Baseline30]
vision.videoBitRate = 1
vision.startVideoCapture()
```